# Design pattern for data layer [.net]

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I work on school enterprise project and I need create data layer with design patterns. Can you give me some hint where to start and how patters could I use ? Thanks

Edit:
I have not use frameworks for ORM.

Comment: Take a look at the Repository/Service pattern which abstracts your logic away to a Business and Data layer

Comment: @Aligator, unfortunately, your question is both too broad and opinion-based.Consider to read some info about patterns (e.g. [Martin Fowler's Catalog](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html)), start coding and return with specific questions after you'll have specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [repository pattern and unit of work](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) pattern

Answer (score 0):

One of the common pattern for the data layer is the [Data Access Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object). Anyway you can also use ready-to-use libraries such as the Microsoft Solution [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx) or [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.info/).

Also you can read this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581778.aspx) with a lot of suggestions